# Why is that i cannot compare two strings using for loop in C language [ If strings are reverse of each other ]

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char string1[100],string2[100];
int count,i=0,j=0;

gets(string1);
gets(string2);

for(i=0;i<strlen(string1)-1;i++)
{
for(j=strlen(string2)-1;j<0;j--)
{
    if(string1[i]==string2[j])
    {
        printf("They are reverse of each other");
    }
    else
        printf("They are not");
    }
}
```

}

/* I am trying to check if ABC and CBA are equal by checking the first index of string1 and last index of string2 and incrementing and decrementing resp. */

Comment: This: `j<0` isn't going to work out very well in a count **down** loop.

Comment: Also, think about what the nested loop will do (one loop inside another).  For each iteration of the outer loop, you will execute all iterations of the inner loop.  Is this what you need?

Comment: You basically have a palindrome. There are plenty of answers to this problem.

Comment: thanks you everyone. New to programming so such silly mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, it is used check both stings are reverse to each other or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s1[100],s2[100];
    int count,i=0,j=0, flag=1;
    gets(s1);
    gets(s2);
    int l1=strlen(s1), l2=strlen(s2);
    if(l1==l2)
    {
        l2--;
        for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        {
            if(s1[i]!=s2[l2-i])
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    if(flag)
        printf("Both are reverse to each other\n");
    else
        printf("Not revrese to each other\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Not revrese to each other\n");
}
```

Comment: thank you praveen.. just started coding.. so...